# HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem() in ASP.NET for small background tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I came a across a nice little tool that has been added to ASP.NET in v4.5.2

I am wandering how safe it is and how one can effectively utilize it in an ASP.NET MVC or Web API scenario.

I know I am always wanting to do a quick and simple fire and forget task in my web applications.  For example:

- Sending an emails/s
- Sending push notifications
- Logging analytics or errors to the db

Now typically I just create a method called

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string to, string body)
{
 //TODO: send email
}
```

and I would use it like so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
 ...
 await SendEmailAsync(User.Identity.Username, "Hello");
return View(); 
}
```

now my concern with this is that, I am delaying the user in order to send my email to them. This doesn't make much sense to me.

So I first considered just doing:

```
Task.Run(()=> SendEmailAsync(User.Identity.Username, "Hello"));
```

however when reading up about this. It is apparently not the best thing to do in IIS environment. (i'm not 100% sure on the specifics).

So this is where I came across `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(x=> SendEmailAsync(User.Identity.Username, "Hello"));`

This is a very quick and easy way to offload the send email task to a background worker and serve up the users `View()` much quicker.

Now I am aware this is not for tasks running longer than `90 seconds` and is not 100% guaranteed executution.

But my question is:

Is `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem()` sufficient for: sending emails, push notifications, db queries etc in a standard ASP.NET web site.

Answer (score 4):

**It depends.**

---

The main benefit of `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is the following, emphasis mine ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893.aspx)):

> Differs from a normal ThreadPool work item in that ASP.NET can keep track of how many work items registered through this API are currently running, and **the ASP.NET runtime will try to delay AppDomain shutdown** until these work items have finished executing.

Essentially, `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` helps you run tasks that might take a couple of seconds by attempting not to shutdown your application while there's still a task running.

Running a normal database query or sending out a push notification should be a matter of a couple hundred milliseconds (or a few seconds); neither should take a very long time and should thus be fine to run within `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

However, there's no guarantee for the task to finish — as you said, the task is not `await`ed. It all depends on the importance of the task to execute. If the task must complete, it's not a good candidate for `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

Comment: So this just provides a semaphore for the IIS Application Pool to prevent timed recycles ? Great answer.