# The lifecycles of a background thread in web-based systems

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

Once a time I did a experimenet saying that once I used something like Thread.IsBackground = true (A background thread) with some heavy work to do in a method for a controller's method. The code snippet looks below:

```
Thread th = new Thread(()=>Thread.Sleep(10000); Log.Write……);
th.IsBackGround = true;
th.Start();
```

In fact, a request for a controller's method won't take so much time (That's JUST AN EXPERIMENT!). When I requested for the controller's specific method. I DIDN'T see anything logged!

I know that because the Thread's lifecycle is as long as ONLY for a simple request. But if I wanna use something like Task (I know that's dependent on Thread.IsBackround = true for a threadpool……,ect).

---

Is it possible? I have several ways now, maybe not very good but wanna know more suggestions about that:

1) To use "Thread" directly with an exception thrown out to abort the "Thread" instance to be recycled by the GC?

2) To use "Task" in net 4.0, with "TaskOptions" to LongWorking (Will it be recycled by the GC and finsh my heavy task?).

3) Any other ideas about a thread that can do heavy work and recycled by the GC when a request goes out in a web-based application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question, but this might be useful for you  [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem() in ASP.NET for small background tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194727/hostingenvironment-queuebackgroundworkitem-in-asp-net-for-small-background-tas)

Comment: Thanks! However would it be possible to use Task with "LongWork"? And will it be automatically recycled by the GC when the task is finished?